# Hdfs file timestamp

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hdfs

I want to get the last_modification time of file on hdfs. I checked HDFS shell guide but did not get any relevant command available.

Hadoop version is 2.4.0. Can anyone suggest how can I get last_modification time of hdfs file?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve timestamp from hadoop ls command and parse it using awk.There is pattern for file/directory time stamp.
For File it is

```
permissions number_of_replicas userid groupid filesize modification_date modification_time filename
```

And Directory it is

```
permissions userid groupid modification_date modification_time dirname
```

6th and 7th field for file gives you modification date and time. You can use below sample for retrieving those information.

```
hadoop fs -ls /textfile | awk '{timestamp= $6  "  "  $7;print timestamp}'
```

Refer documentation for ls command.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html
Hope this will help.

Comment: if you want to parse that datetime programmatically, you may have better luck with `hadoop fs -stat` http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#stat

Comment: I am trying to run the above-mentioned command inside the shell script. it is not giving correct output. It is giving HH:MM in new line